# activities resume from homescreen launcher in emulator, but not on android device

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, resume

My android application has a login screen that is launched as the main activity with intents as follows:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Nothing else is out of the ordinary (that I am aware of, concerning the other activities, etc, no additional intents set on those or anything).

With the emulator, if I login and the second activity is launched, then I press the home button, if I launch the app again from a homescreen shortcut the task returns to the second activity. This is the desired behavior, as I don't want the user to have to login over and over again.

With both an HTC Incredible and a Droid X (only phones I have access to), if I login and the second activity launches, then press the home button, if I relaunch the app from a homescreen shortcut, it always launches the login activity, which is not the desired result. I want it to resume at the second activity where I left off.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this works as intended with the emulator but not on the phones? Thank you very much.

Comment: Well do you have anything in the code that justifies the fact you see it return to second activity in emulator? Do you use onPause and onResume ? It's also possible that those devices could be having task managers that are killing your application.

Comment: From reading the documentation I was under the impression it should work the way it is on the emulator and that handling onPause or onResume wasn't necessary. Also, on the task killer note, if I click back when I launch the application the second time around, I go from the login screen to the activity I hoped would have been resumed. So the activity stack appears intact.

Comment: I also just discovered that if I resume the app by holding the home screen button down and choosing the app from the recently used list that pops up, that it resumes to the last activity I was on properly. So it seems to just be an issue from the app launcher shortcut or a home screen shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had completely uninstalled the app and deleted the shortcut from my home screen on the phone. Then it started working. My guess is it was the old shortcut on the home screen holding on to iffy intents or something (because im pretty sure I've uninstalled it a few times to no avail). Once everything was uninstalled/reinstalled and a new shortcut was created on the home screen it is working as intended. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same behaviour on my HTC Desire. If I install the apk from my computer either by using eclipse or by command line via

> adb install

everything is fine. If I install from the file on the phone, I get the behaviour you describe. I wonder what install/update via the market does but am afraid to give it like that to the users.

The difference to your case is that uninstall does not change a thing. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the shortcut in the launcher area that gets installed on the fresh install, to run the app? It was a combination of an uninstall and shortcut deletion that enabled mine to start working as intended. I think the shortcut deletion alone most likely would have done it.